# Not true color with imagecreatetruecolor & imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, image, colors

Hy there,

I use this code to resize my images to improve size...

```
<?php
    // File
    $filename = 'ok.jpg';
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $ratio = ($width >= $height) ? 683 : 1152;
    $percent = $ratio / $height;

    // New sizes
    $new_width = $width * $percent;
    $new_height = $height * $percent;

    // Apply new sizes
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    // Save
    imagejpeg($image_p, 'tes.jpg', 80);
    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($image_p);
```

But I saw a problem with the colors quality... image looks more grey than original.

Original picture : 
[image: original]

And after resizing : 
[image: original]

What can I do to keep same colors ?
Thanks

Comment: PHP GD works with sRGB color space. Your original image is probably not in sRGB color space. That's it. GD just doesn't work with color profiles, you need extra software to do that. For instance: [Convert to sRGB color space](https://cimage.se/doc/convert-to-srgb). I have no experience with this myself, therefore I posted this as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: Yes, "Adobe RGB" is not "sRGB". Many different color spaces use "RGB" but are different nonetheless.

Comment: It's that... I gonna search to that way, thank's !